# Laravel 8.15 How to solve eloquent relationship problem for the new version

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see in the below all of my codes in Laravel for new version 8.15. In one to one relationships when I use route to get info. from user table then I don't get anything, and same case for the inverse relationships. After that I have tried for the one to many relationship but when I run the server then I got only one result, where many information are supposed to get. But one to many inverse relationship's case I didn't get any result.

My Database: In [Users table]--> id, name, content etc columns. And [Posts table]--> id, title, content, user_id(foreign key).

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/post', function(){

    $post = User::find(1)->post; // One to one relationship
    return $post;

});

    
    Route::get('/user', function(){
    
        $user = Post::find(2); // One to one (Inverse) Relationship
        return $user;
    
    });


Route::get('/posts', function(){

    $user = User::find(1); // One to many relationships
    //return $user;
    foreach($user->posts as $post){

        echo $post . "<br>";

    }
});


Route::get('/users', function(){

    $user = Post::find(1); // One to many (inverse) relationships
    return $user;
    
});
```

User model **User.php**

```
public function post(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Post'); // For one to one relationship
}


public function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post'); // For one to many relationship
}
```

Post model **Post.php**

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User'); // One to one relationship

}

public function users(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User'); // One to many relationship

}
```

Comment: For your one-to-many, you're only getting one because you're returning the value inside of the loop. You can just return `$user->posts`

Comment: @aynber Using $user->posts that doesn’t seem to be changing